# Woocommerce custom add to cart button with custom checkout page

Tags: php, wordpress, button, woocommerce, product

I have a Woocommerce store, I was looking to add another add to cart button named "Try now" to a particular category(not to all the categories). When the user clicks on "try now", it gets redirected to the custom checkout page.

On custom checkout page, try-now products can be added up-to 5 products max, total is fixed as 500 for all the try now products and payment only by card.

I have found the following codes.

**Code to replace add to cart button**

```
function remove_loop_button(){
 if (in_array( 10, $product->category_ids))
  remove_action(‘woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item’,‘woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart’, 10);
}
add_action(‘init’,’remove_loop_button’);

add_action(‘woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item’,’replace_add_to_cart’);
function replace_add_to_cart() {
global $product;
$link = $product->get_permalink();
echo ‘<a href=”‘.esc_attr($link).'”>Try Now</a>’;
}
```

**And also this code to customize checkout page from [Make 2 different WooCommerce checkout pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25164867/woocommerce-multiple-checkout-pages)**

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );

function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
global $woocommerce;

//assuming only one product in cart
foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
    $_product = $values['data'];
}

switch ($_product->id) {
    case '666': //product id for product 1
        //do stuff with the checkout fields
        break;
    case '999': //product id for product 2
        //do stuff with the checkout fields
        break;
}

return $fields;
}
```

I know it's quite complicated, Can any one please suggest me where to start? Or any hint will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @LoicTheAztec

Comment: Any suggestions for me @LoicTheAztec

Comment: This question is just too broad as this needs a lot of code using php ajax and jQuery… This can not be done in a simple way.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know it's too complex, can i achieve it on woocommerce?? May be based on meta value changing a cart and checkout. @LoicTheAztec