# How do I create multiple checkout pages for WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Is it possible to create multiple checkout pages for WooCommerce?

The reason is that I want to customize many things on the checkout pages (eg. graphics, text, offers and popups) depending on the products that a user chooses.

While I can do these all on a single page, it would be a lot easier to organize them in separate pages.

**What I have tried**

I tried the various solutions listed here but none of them worked:
[Woocommerce Multiple Checkout Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25164867/woocommerce-multiple-checkout-pages/)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you are trying to create multiple checkout pages templates in order to use them depending on certain conditions.

At first glance you could try [overriding the WooCommerce templates](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/).

Please note that the consensus is to avoid having an overly complex checkout process, as a poorly designed checkout user experience will [negatively affect the conversion rate](https://www.bolt.com/blog/checkout-page/).

If you provide more details about the conditions you are trying to work with it might make it easier to help you find a solution.